# Please help me understand one part of reading a preference

Tags: java, android, boolean, preferences

So I am still a bit new to java/android and I am attempting to read a preference value, but I am trying to understand each part about it so it makes a little more sense to me...

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean soundEnabledPref = sharedPref.getBoolean("sound", soundEnabled);
```

in the getBoolean, I am trying to understand what the first string is "sound", and what the soundEnabled boolean is for.

so I have declared soundEnabled up top as a boolean, i am guessing this is what stores the value that I am retrieving?

what is the purpose of the first string though "sound"?  I want to make sure I am naming it correctly if its being used to store something, or if I am referencing something with it then I probably need to name it something different.

I have read through the developer documentation and still am a bit confused so if someone could just give me a quick explanation a bit more broken down I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **"sound"** is the key, under which you are looking for the value
- **soundEnabled** is a boolean variable, which has some value - true or false; this value will be used as default value for soundEnabledPref in case there is no "sound" key; it can be written like that also:

  ```
  boolean soundEnabledPref = sharedPref.getBoolean("sound", true);
  ```

  If there is no "sound" key, soundEnabledPref will take the default value of true

A good practice for keys is to use constants - you WILL avoid simple typo errors later down the line, eg.:

```
public static final String KEY_SOUND = "sound";
```

Then

```
boolean soundEnabledPref = sharedPref.getBoolean(ClassNameWhereItsDefined.KEY_SOUND, true);
```

Comment: so to be clear, if I set the android:key in the preference to pref_sounds that is what I would put where I currently have "sound" correct?  and then the second value is default in case there is no value found from the preference?

Comment: Yes, for example if in strings.xml, you have <string name="pref_sound">pref_sound</string> and then in preference set android:key="@string/pref_sound", you can use it here as: boolean soundEnabledPref = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_sound), true);

Answer (score 1):

"sound" is the key corresponding to which you will have a value stored in your `SharedPreferences`.

This is described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) as well.

In simpler terms, you can consider it as a variable which will hold a value.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preference using Dictionary concept    it  Key , Value pair as dictionary it save any  key with string   and   value as object shared preference is safe type , when you want save integer you using method putInt or putBoolean to save boolean , and when you retrieve from shared preference also return for you strong type after it cast value for you ,

hope it helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You can store several things in shared preferences, so you use keys to identify what values to set and what values to retrieve later on.


In this case, `sound` is your key.


At some point in your app, you called `SharedPreferences.Editor.putBoolean("sound", myBoolean);`.


At some point later in your app you call `SharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound", defaultBoolean);` to find out what the value of `myBoolean` was. In this call, `defaultBoolean` is simply the default value you want to get if by any chances you never called `SharedPreferences.Editor.putBoolean` and therefore a value for `"sound"` does not exist.